# How do I make backfaces override transparency into a flat color?

Tags: materials

I want to be able to change the outer edge seen as A into B where the transparent part is shown as green.

As long as it looks like the B version on this image.
Without changing any aspect of the inner sphere. 
While keeping the toon shading as is.
Without adding any additional mesh.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodes to set different materials to the front and the back faces.

In your case, I would use the outer mesh exclusively for the outline, with a node material:

[image: outline material]

The green materials is shadeless.

Then, again using nodes, you can mix the shadeless and the toon shaded materials for the inner shape:

[image: inner material and render result]

Comment: Request: "Without changing any aspect of the inner sphere." Changes the aspect of the inner sphere.

Comment: Even if you didn't get the answer perfectly you did help me understand more about nodes and I appreciate your answer.